# Symfony: где делать flush: в контролелре или сервисе?

Tags: юнит-тесты, symfony, doctrine

Приведу пример кода, для пояснения дилемы:

1 вариант:

```
 ArticleController
    {
        public function createArticle(Request $request, ArticleService $articeService, UserService $userService,  EntityManager $em){
             $articeService->create(CreateArticleDTO::createFromRequest($request));
             $userService->incrementArticleCount($this->getUser());
             $em->flush();
        }
    }

    ArticleService{
        public function (CreateArticleDTO $dto)
        {
            /// create $entity
            $this->entityManager->persist($entity);
        }
    }

   UserService{
        public function (User $user)
        {
            $user->setArticelCount($user->getArticelCount()+1);
        }
    }
```

2 вариант.

```
 ArticleController
        {
            public function createArticle(Request $request, ArticleService $articeService, UserService $userService){
                 $articeService->create(CreateArticleDTO::createFromRequest($request));
                 $userService->incrementArticleCount($this->getUser());
            }
        }

        ArticleService{
            public function (CreateArticleDTO $dto)
            {
                /// create $entity
                $this->entityManager->persist($entity);
                $this->entityManager->flush();
            }
        }

       UserService{
            public function (User $user)
            {
                $user->setArticelCount($user->getArticelCount()+1);
                $this->entityManager->flush();
            }
        }
```

1 Варинт.

За: Где то видел, что это было в лучших практиках. Но воможно это было в эпоху 2 симфони, а возможно я вообще ошибаюсь. Смысл - что все сущности сохранятся в однйо транзакции. Или всё или ничего.

Против: занижаем связность. Т.е. нельзя быть уверенным, что вызвав данный сервис - статья сохранится. Придет другой разработчик, увидит название, вызовет - а статья не сохраняется. 
В тестировании надо отдельнов вызывать flush, чтобы проверить что статья сохранится. Вроде тестируем сервис, а вроде нужно что-то поверх него вызывать, чтобы проверить работоспособность. Если будет пакетное сохранение, то все равно придется вызывать flush в сервисах - архитектура будет не единой.

2) Вараинт: ну единственный минус - это несколько транзакций вместо одной. Что вроде как против тех же лучших практик. Возможно что-то еще, чего я не знаю.

Comment: Возможно, я подниму холивар, но на мой субъективный взгляд, контроллер должен быть тонким и обрабатывать запросы / отдавать результаты, все остальное должно быть вынесено в другие места. В вашем же случае, flush лучше вынести в репозиторий

Comment: @StereoFlo уж где где, но точно не в реопзитории. Так как если делать несколько запросов - будет несколько транзакций. В лучшизх практиках тоже говорится что флаш должен быть один по возможности (т.е. 1 транзакция).

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, все таки, как я писал в комментариях, лучше использовать репозиторий по его прямому назначению, однако ваш подход с выполнением всего в контроллере, нарушает принцип единственной обязанности, в будущем, с таким кодом вы это, возможно прочувствуете. Я накидал кода, как пример, подчерпнуть для себя что-то или нет - решать вам. В данном конкретном случае, сохранение произойдет каскадом, ну и опять же, получается, каждая часть отвечает за что-то одно. Как следствие, пропадает необходимость в хранимом значении articlesCount.

```
<?php

// entity
class User
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned": true})
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection<Article>
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="user")
     */
    private $articles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->articles = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addArticle(Article $article): void
    {
        $this->articles->add($article);
    }

    public function getArticlesCount(): int
    {
        return $this->articles->count();
    }
}

// entity
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="articles", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;
    private $vsyakiyParam1;
    private $vsyakiyParam2;

    public function __construct(User $user, array $vsyakieParametry)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        $this->vsyakiyParam1 = $vsyakieParametry['vsyakiyParam1'] ?? null;
        $this->vsyakiyParam2 = $vsyakieParametry['vsyakiyParam2'] ?? null;
    }
}

class ArticleController
{
    public function createArticle(Request $request, ArticleService $articeService)
    {
        $articeService->create($this->getUser(), CreateArticleDTO::createFromRequest($request));
    }
}

class ArticleService
{
    /**
     * @var ArticleRepository
     */
    private $articleRepository;

    public function __construct(ArticleRepository $articleRepository)
    {
        $this->articleRepository = $articleRepository;
    }

    public function create(User $user, CreateArticleDTO $dto)
    {
        $articleEntity = new Article($user, $dto);
        $this->articleRepository->save($articleEntity);
    }
}

class ArticleRepository
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function save(Article $article): void
    {
        $this->em->persist($article);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, данный код работает на Low Coupling , но работает против атомарности. Таким образом придется выносить в уровень сервиса (в вашем примере) начало и конец транзакции если будет несколько операций. 
Хотя соглашусь с тем - что ваше предложение является более абстрактным и фреймворконезависимым, если его дорабатывать транзакциями .

Comment: Тут надо понимать, что и как вы хотите сделать (добавить в БД). Возможно, ваши сущности уже связаны друг с другом и все это можно сохранить одним большим объектом в репозитории. Таким образом, получится одна транзакция. В случаях, когда сущности не связаны, между собой, имеет смысл делать несколько запросов.

Comment: Честно говоря мне более близок этот пример https://youtu.be/eU4ajVB9Lz4?t=851 , но спасибо за пример и вариант.